# How to estimate the size of the payments after upgrading from trial to paid account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Today I received a notification: "There are still seven days until your trial expires. Upgrade your account now to enable automatic billing and prevent loss of service when your trial expires. Upgrade now!".

The FAQ says: "You can estimate the cost of using Google Cloud by translating your estimate of the resources you'll use into estimated monthly charges with the pricing calculator, or by consulting the pricing page."
The [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) has many new specific terms. I’m not sure that I understand all of them correctly.

How to estimate how much I will pay for the account after the upgrade? I would be very grateful for a simple explanation or step-by-step instructions for a correct estimate.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you should have $300 in credits during your trial. All spendings should be visible in billing, except the bill will be 0 because the credit was applied.

- **Go to your project** at https://console.cloud.google.com/
- **Select "Billing"** either from the dashboard or from the side nav
- **View your report** for detailed spending on all services you use

This should continue to reflect your spending in the future if you wish to stay with your current infrastructure. Otherwise, you can always use the calculator and match the services you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on [View Your Billing Reports and Cost Trends](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports) might be helpful for you. It includes a step by step guide for reading and understanding billing charts,changing chart settings, chart style, data order, preset views, viewing your forecasted cost, viewing your credits etc.